# Multiple Python files into one RPM package

Tags: python, python-3.x, rpm, rpm-spec

I am trying to generate an RPM package for a Python project that includes several source files, like:

- runner.py
- constants.py
- helpers.py
- configuration.py
- ...

The project includes this runner, a CLI and a GUI, which I excluded from the list. The files other than `runner.py` are the code pieces shared among other executable ones. My intention is to create an RPM package for each. If I manage to solve one of them, It would be easier to solve the others.

My current `build.sh` looks like below. It is a fork of some other project's SPEC and build script.

```
...
# Generate and fill the source folders
cp "${SCRIPT_DIR}"/../runner.py package-"${VERSION}"/usr/sbin/runner
chmod +x package-"${VERSION}"/usr/sbin/runner
cp "${SCRIPT_DIR}"/../constants.py package-"${VERSION}"/usr/sbin/constants
chmod +x package-"${VERSION}"/usr/sbin/constants
cp "${SCRIPT_DIR}"/../helpers.py package-"${VERSION}"/usr/sbin/helpers
chmod +x package-"${VERSION}"/usr/sbin/helpers
cp "${SCRIPT_DIR}"/../configuration.py package-"${VERSION}"/usr/sbin/configuration
chmod +x package-"${VERSION}"/usr/sbin/configuration
...
tar --create --file package-"${VERSION}".tar.gz package-"${VERSION}"
...
# Remove out build directory, now that we have our tarball
rm -fr package-"${VERSION}"
mv package-"${VERSION}".tar.gz ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/
cp rpmbuild/SPECS/* ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/
echo 'Building RPM package based on SPECS/package.spec'

rpmbuild -bb -D 'debug_package %{nil}' ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/package.spec
```

And below you can see the related part in `package.spec`:

```
...
%install
rpm -fr $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/%{_sbindir}
cp usr/sbin/runner.py $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/%{_sbindir}/runner
cp usr/sbin/constants.py $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/%{_sbindir}/constants
cp usr/sbin/helpers.py $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/%{_sbindir}/helpers
cp usr/sbin/configuration.py $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/%{_sbindir}/configuration
...
```

When RPM package is installed, the files other than runner should not be in /usr/sbin/ directory. It is not the expected result here. So I believe the cleanest way is to have one file per application but that prevents me to share the common parts. What is the recommended approach in this case?

Comment: I would recommend creating a Python distribution package first, so that the spec file does little more than run commands like `pip install ...` or `python setup.py ...`.

Comment: I am new to Python. I did not even consider that an option. I'll give it a shot.